# how to create custom control using jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to create a control using the jquery ui framework. I know that I have to use as base the jquery.ui.widget.js as a factory.

This control I want to create has a behavior similar to the tabcontrol. I want to create a tileview, so when yo select a content in a panel of multiples views... it expands and the others collapse to a side of the control.
Like this one http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TileView/FirstLook
Is there any tutorial, step by step to create a custom widget?

Comment: Check this out might help you http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/

Comment: Fwiw (a short ten years later), Shankar's link 404s, but [an archived copy is here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120217131640/http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good starting point is jQuery UI documentation on this topic: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget-factory

At minimum your widget must implement following code (sample taken from documentation):

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.widget( "demo.multi", {

    // These options will be used as defaults
    options: { 
      clear: null
    },

    // Set up the widget
    _create: function() {
    },

    // Use the _setOption method to respond to changes to options
    _setOption: function( key, value ) {
      switch( key ) {
        case "clear":
          // handle changes to clear option
          break;
      }

      // In jQuery UI 1.8, you have to manually invoke the _setOption method from the base widget
      $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply( this, arguments );
      // In jQuery UI 1.9 and above, you use the _super method instead
      this._super( "_setOption", key, value );
    },

    // Use the destroy method to clean up any modifications your widget has made to the DOM
    destroy: function() {
      // In jQuery UI 1.8, you must invoke the destroy method from the base widget
      $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
      // In jQuery UI 1.9 and above, you would define _destroy instead of destroy and not call the base method
    }
  });
}( jQuery ) );
```